# Unable to deploy outlook add in with windows installer

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have developed an outlook 2013 VSTO add-in (a ribbon and a button which offers a DB synchronisation). To deploy this, I've created an install shield LE project which contains the registry entries for the add-in, the .vsto file and the required dependencies. 
The build of the installer is okay, as it gives me a .msi file that I can run on other computers. The installation is fine, but when I run outlook, it shows me an error message and it doesn't load the add-in.

[Error message link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiIOD.png)

What can I do to fix this?
The error message is saying that the manifest is missing but this file is never mentionned in the code or in the config files, it doesn't even exists...

EDIT :

I've opened the .vsto file and it mention the manifest.dll missing file, but I've never mentionned it myself in the code.

[.VSTO file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyaPJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is the manifest file in the Folder ?

Did you sign the Project ?

Maybe the spaces in your path are the Problem.

I use a Batch file to install - much easier and you don't need to be Admin to install:

Install.bat:

```
SET KEY=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Tom.OutlookExporter

REG ADD %KEY% /f
REG ADD %KEY% /f /v Description /t REG_SZ /d "Tom's Outlook Exporter"
REG ADD %KEY% /f /v FriendlyName /t REG_SZ /d "Tom's Outlook Exporter" 
REG ADD %KEY% /f /v LoadBehavior /t REG_DWORD /d 3
REG ADD %KEY% /f /v Manifest /t REG_SZ /d "%CD%\OutlookExporter.vsto|vstolocal"
```

Uninstall.bat:

```
SET KEY=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Tom.OutlookExporter

REG DELETE %KEY% /f
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. First, thank you for your help? I tried your installation way but I still doesn't work :(

Comment: Maybe it's the signature. See my manifest at the bottom:
[link](http://www.tomtempo.net/shared/outlookexporter.dll.manifest.txt)

Comment: I am not using ClickOnce, I use InstallShield Limited Edition. 
There is no signature but I think the problem is that the VSTO wants the .dll.manifest (as mentionned on the second link in the edit part) but I don't know how to change it or to delete it... (once again, thank you for the help)

Comment: Outlook needs the ClickOnce Manifest for using the AddIn.
I didn't deploy with ClickOnce, just sign the Click Once Manifest.
This should be default when you create a new Office AddIn Project.
Once this Manifest is generated while compiling, include it in your Installation Folder, via InstallShield, or Copy and Paste or ClickOnce.